# On resolving build.gradle file with org.springframework.boot plugin, PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9 error shown

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}
```

On attempting to build the gradle build in IntelliJ Idea, below error message displayed.

> PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'cucumber-spring-boot-example'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file /Users/sritejkurapati/.gradle/caches/jars-9/50be9eebfc8073d47d23166e55741b83/spring-core-6.0.7.jar.
>
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Tried deleting .gradle cache files and jar files but still error shown.

Comment: What version of Gradle do you use? Note that Spring Boot requires Java 17 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes) and to run Gradle with Java 17 you need at least Gradle version 7.3 (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)

Comment: I am using gradle 7.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the gradle wrapper version to 7.6. It fixed my problem

There is a post from Noah Hsu:
https://noahhsu.medium.com/what-problems-did-i-solve-when-migrating-spring-boot-to-3-0-0-796b545ec00